# Entities inheriting by SINGLE_TABLE method are treated as the same objects by the base ounce during the test

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm doing an integration test at Spring. He used the dbUnit library. For testing, I use objects created in XML

```
@DatabaseSetup("MoviePersistenceServiceImplIntegrationTests/init.xml")
```

This is what the file looks like https://pastebin.com/YQ4nMEfn. I have created a [movie](https://github.com/JonkiPro/popcorn/blob/develop/popcorn-core/src/main/java/com/jonki/popcorn/core/jpa/entity/MovieEntity.java) object and three [information objects](https://github.com/JonkiPro/popcorn/blob/develop/popcorn-core/src/main/java/com/jonki/popcorn/core/jpa/entity/movie/MovieInfoEntity.java): a [other title](https://github.com/JonkiPro/popcorn/blob/develop/popcorn-core/src/main/java/com/jonki/popcorn/core/jpa/entity/movie/MovieOtherTitleEntity.java), [release date](https://github.com/JonkiPro/popcorn/blob/develop/popcorn-core/src/main/java/com/jonki/popcorn/core/jpa/entity/movie/MovieReleaseDateEntity.java) and [outline](https://github.com/JonkiPro/popcorn/blob/develop/popcorn-core/src/main/java/com/jonki/popcorn/core/jpa/entity/movie/MovieOutlineEntity.java) of the story (entities differ by `dtype`). 
In hyperlinks, I gave addresses to files on GitHub. All of this information objects inherit from the entity https://github.com/JonkiPro/popcorn/blob/develop/popcorn-core/src/main/java/com/jonki/popcorn/core/jpa/entity/movie/MovieInfoEntity.java using the `@Inheritance (strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)`

When I want to get a list of other titles

```
 List<MovieReleaseDateEntity> resultList = movieEntity.getReleaseDates()
```

I getting
https://zapodaj.net/827bf8471bdb0.png.html
All three objects of the MovieReleaseDateEntity type, and should receive only one. As you can see in the picture http s://zapodaj.net/205b4deaf1177.png.html, in the element from `ID 4`, which is `OUTLINE` type, it set `release date` and `country` to `null`.

Why after getting entities from the `getReleaseDates` list gets all objects inheriting from the `MovieInfoEntity` even though they have another `dtype`?